# How to find how similar two vectors are, while giving weight to their lengths?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, vectors, sums-of-squares

I [asked a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891629/determine-similarity-of-a-sequence-of-1-1-pairs) about this yesterday and got a really good response!

Apparently I should use the euclidian (sum of squares) distance between the two vectors.

This works well, but I'm having a bit of an issue.

Here's why this is a problem:

```
 [ [
-1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 ] ]
```

The answer to this one is `0.684`

Considering that every pair matches except one, it should be much higher. I'm not sure if this is "technically" accurate, but I feel like it should be really close to 1, no? All the 40 data points are 1 except for one and it's only at .68.

Is there another algorithm that makes the result closer to intuition or that allows me to more heavily weight the length of the vectors or something?

Thanks for reading!

**Edit:** I was just walking around and I thought of what I *think* the real answer should be close to. Because every point is the same except one and there's 40 points, I figure it should probably be around `1 - (1 / 40) = .975`? Or maybe `1 - 2(1 / 40) = 0.95` because it goes from -1 to 1 and not just 0 to 1. Not sure, but that definitely sounds more right!

Comment: Keep in mind that the denominator in the definition of $D$ should match the number of entries.  So for your 1,000 element list, we'd compute
$$
D = 1 - \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{1000} (x_k - y_k)^2}{1000}}
$$
which comes out to $0.955$ in the case where they match in all entries except for one

Comment: Err yeah that's true I got confused on that part. Hmm, not really sure what the problem is then. The answers for my data sets don't look correct. I think I might need to put this question on hold for a minute while I investigate further.

Comment: Okay, I think I know the problem. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Sorry about the confusion but I've edited the post to better explain my issue!

Comment: You could consider [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)

Comment: @ChronBag try out
$$
D = 1 - \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N} |x_k - y_k|}{N}
$$
see if that works any better for you

Comment: Hey that tentatively looks pretty good! Much faster too which is a HUGE plus. Thanks I'll try it out for a bit and hopefully keep it!